# why does jqGrid give "Error: No url is set" if cellSubmit is 'clientArray'?

Tags: jqgrid, tablecelleditor

using jqGridversion 3.7.2

I thought that if I set cellSubmit: 'clientArray' then the grid does NOT need a url to post data. I'm trynig to just capture the changed value locally and process it manually, not auto trigger a server event. Yet when I try to exit an edited cell I still get the "Error: No url is set" dialog.

grid options def:

```
$(".mytable").jqGrid({
    datatype: 'local',
    data: myData,
    colModel: colModelDef,
    sortname: 'date',
    sortorder: 'desc',
    width: 950,
    height: 550,
    shrinkToFit: false,
    rownumbers: true,
    multiselect: true,
    cellEdit: true,
    beforeSaveCell: function() {
        //rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol
        alert(arguments[2]);
    },
    cellSubmit: 'clientArray'
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

turns out it was a typo, should read "cellsubmit" not "cellSubmit" works like a charm. [Thanks Tony!](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/confusion-regarding-cellsubmit-clientarray/&value=3515&type=8&include=0&search=1&ret=all)

Answer (score 0):

Before all you should replace **class selector** `$(".mytable")` to the **id selector** like `$("#mygrid")`. If the `<table>` element not yet has the id you should add it. jqGrid works intern permanent with the id of the table element and construct ids of other DOM elements based on the id of the `<table>` element. So the usage of `<table>` without id can not good work.

If a simple change of the selector will not help you should include full code of an example which can be used to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

add follow attr and the error will be gone

```
loadonce:true
```